# Add blocks via layout.xml - magento

Tags: magento

I'm new to Magento so sry if it's a bit of a newbie question.

I was adding these blocks from a controller:

```
$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc/adminhtml_abc_edit'))
     ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('abc/adminhtml_abc_edit_tabs'));
```

The blocks were added. However now I'm trying to add the blocks via layout.xml. I've tried the following:

```
<abc_adminhtml_abc_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="abc/adminhtml_abc_edit" name="form">
                <reference name="left">
                    <block type="abc/adminhtml_abc_edit_tabs" name="tabs"/>
                </reference>
            </block>
        </reference>
 </abc_adminhtml_abc_edit>
```

but it didn't work out and I can't find how to do it right...

what's the correct way?

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

Find out how, after looking at some of the layout xml files of Magento. This did the trick:

```
<abc_adminhtml_abc_edit>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="abc/adminhtml_abc_edit" name="form"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="left">
            <block type="abc/adminhtml_abc_edit_tabs" name="tabs"/>
        </reference>
</abc_adminhtml_abc_edit>
```